# Collection view indexpathforitematpoint item

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get the item value from the cole below?

```
let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.collectionView)
let cellIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(pointInTable)
println(cellIndexPath)
```

I am currently shown this but need the integer value.

```
Optional(<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1})
```

Comment: What "integer value"? What part of that log message do you not understand? You don't know what an NSIndexPath is? You don't know what an Optional is? What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the row from a NSIndexPath.

`NSIndexPath.row`.

You have to determine yourself the number corresponding to a defined `NSIndexPath`. `NSIndexPath` contains row and col coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I needed by using the line below:

```
cellIndexPath?.item
```